# Add 3 IF statements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now i have just 1 IF statement :

Its like: if **4 Days Paris** is selected & 1 people selected, then show a div :

```
if (personPValue == "4 Days Paris" && numAantal == "1") {
    $("#t-extracost-90").show();
    extraCost90 = 90;
} else {
    $("#t-extracost-90").hide();
    extraCost90 = 0;
}
```

But i want to add more selected option in the if statement, right now i am just copy this and edit and past for a new rule, that is working fine,

> Can i do it in a shorter way? Because right now my page is getting longer

I just want to do something like this:

```
if (personPValue == "4 Days Paris" && "3 Days London" && "3 Days Italy" numAantal == "1")
```

But that is not working :(

IF **4 Days Paris** & **4 Days London** & **3 Days Italy** is selected & **1** people than show the div: **#t-extracost-90**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `personPValue ==` in `if` condition:

```
if (personPValue == "4 Days Paris" && personPValue == "3 Days London" && personPValue == "3 Days Italy" && numAantal == "1")
```

I believe, you want `or` instead of `and`:

```
if ((personPValue == "4 Days Paris" || personPValue == "3 Days London" || personPValue == "3 Days Italy") && numAantal == "1")
```

Comment: Try this: `if ((personPValue == "4 Days Paris" || personPValue == "3 Days London" || personPValue == "3 Days Italy") && numAantal == "1")`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you mean OR... in that case I would use a switch statement or a dict that holds all the correct options.
1. using a switch:

```
switch (personPValue) {
  case "4 Days Paris":
  case "4 Days London":
  case "3 Days Italy":
  if (numAantal == "1"){
    $("#t-extracost-90").show();
  }
}
```

2. using a dict:

```
var allowedOptions = {"4 Days Paris":true,"4 Days London":true,"3 Days Italy":true};
if (personPValue in allowedOptions && numAantal == "1"){
          $("#t-extracost-90").show();
        }
```

Comment: The answer from @Tushar is my solution, and the fastest way! But anyway thanks for you answer

Comment: Fast is not always the best.. :-)
what if you will have more options in the future? editing that condition will become messy

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, can find demo in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/5udt3jsc/). It is completely working example.

JS

```
var numAantal = "1";

$('#test').click(function(){
    var items = [];
        $('option:selected').each(function(){ 
            alert(this.value);
        items.push(this.value); 
    });
    if (($.inArray('3', items) != -1) && ($.inArray('4', items) != -1) && numAantal === '1'){
        alert('show');
    }
    else {
        alert('hide');
    } 
});
```

HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="3">3 Days London</option>
  <option value="4">4 Days Paris</option>
  <option value="5">other</option>
  <option value="6">other2</option>
</select>

<input type='button' value='test' id='test'/>
```

Comment: This one is Also GOOD & FAST ! I will try this for sure! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to contanstly compare your var to your wanted value:

```
   if (value="4 Days..." && value=="3 Days..." && value=="3 Days..." && num="1")
```

Anyway, as you stated it, this will never work, in this IF statement EVERY part of it needs to be true, so the var "value" needs to have three different values at the same time to work.
There are two options:
 - You have three different vars value1, value2, value3, in this case the previous statement will work.
- You have only one var that can have three different values, one of them needs to be true together with the num=="1", in this case you are looking for something like this:

```
  if ((value=="val1" || value=="val2" || value=="val3") && num="1")
```

Comment: There was no answer when I first opened it, I was too slow apparently :)